# convert string with time to date only

Tags: mysql

I have a column which holds date values as varchar as in the format of

```
date_n                    date_s
2016-11-10::12:36:05      2016-NOV-10::12:36:05
2016-11-10                2016-NOV-10
```

Now all I need is to get date from both of columns but I am only able to get from column `date_n` along with timestamp and nothing from `date_s` The query I tried as

```
SELECT * FROM table where CAST(date_n AS DATE)=CURDATE();
```

which returns both element as result but when I change `date_n` to `date_s` returns empty and all I need output as `date` only no time stamp

So is there any way to sort this out

Comment: you want both condition or one

Comment: Have you tried `WHERE DATE(date_s) = DATE()`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this logic

```
WHERE  TRIM(UPPER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_s,':',1))) = 
TRIM(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'
-',UPPER(SUBSTRING((MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MONTH(NOW()),'%m'))),1,3)),'-',DAY(NOW())))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE date_s LIKE CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',UPPER(SUBSTRING(MONTHNAME(NOW()), 1, 3)),SUBSTRING(CURRENT_DATE(), 8), '%');
```